# Paperclip processor to return the file untouched

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm creating a Paperclip processor which would shrink the image below a certain threshold if the image is larger than the threshold. If the image is already small enough it should leave the image untouched.

The processor works well when the file is larger than the threshold but when it should leave the file untouched Paperclip throws an `IOError: closed stream`. What should I return from the #make method to avoid the error? Creating and returning a duplicate tempfile from the original file just feels wrong.

```
module Paperclip
  class Shrinker < Processor

    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @file = file
      @instance = options[:instance]
      @current_format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    def make
      if @file.size > 4000000
        do_the_processing_and_return_a_tempfile
      else
        @file
      end
    end

    ...

  end
end
```

And the end of the stacktrace:

```
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/io_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:8:in `rewind'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:52:in `block in flush_writes'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:37:in `each'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:37:in `flush_writes'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:239:in `save'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/paperclip-4.1.1/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:88:in `block in add_active_record_callbacks'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `instance_exec'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `block in make_lambda'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
 # /home/mika/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
 # ./app/models/email.rb:254:in `block in save_images'
 # ./app/models/email.rb:243:in `each'
 # ./app/models/email.rb:243:in `save_images'
```

My processor does not show up in the stacktrace but it is run and it is the source of the issue.

Comment: Try returning `File.new(@file.path)` instead of `@file`

Comment: Hey, thanks! That worked :) You may add it as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked :) will add as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `@file` instance is a closed file object, and paperclip is having issues working with the closed stream of file.

You may try returning

```
File.new(@file.path)
```

instead of `@file` to create a new open file stream from the file so that paperclip will be able to manipulate the open file stream without issues.